# ssrs report returns no data and there is no error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to access report via reporting server in internet explorer.
after i give the credentials and parameters it shows nothing. And it doesn't shows any error.

When i try to access report via website it doesn't shows any data.

I am using shared Data source.and uses stored procedures to get the data from the database

is anyone can tell me why this is happening and how can i solve this problem?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is your `Stored Procedure` returning any records when you run it in SSMS? Start with displaying your parameters in the report.

Comment: Run the query you used to produce the store proc with the parameter you selected and check if it returns any data. that should be the starting point

Comment: You aren't giving us much information to go on, to try to help you. Can you post your stored procedures, sample data and what the report should look like.